# Ninject вызов конструктора с параметрами

Tags: c#, asp.net, архитектура, ninject

Есть метод где создается зависимость:

```
public override void Load()
{

    Bind<IExcelUpdater>().To<ExcelUpdater>();

    //Example
    //Bind<IRepository>().To<BookRepository>()
    //   .WithConstructorArgument( "context", new BookContext() );
}
```

Я хочу создать одну зависимость с параметрами конструктора, но параметры для него хранятся в файле `Web.config` в разделе `AppSettings`.

Конечно можно было бы сделать так:

```
public override void Load()
{

    Bind<IExcelUpdater>().To<ExcelUpdater>();
    string MainLoopTimeout = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "MainLoopTimeout" ];
    //Example
    Bind<IRepository>().To<BookRepository>()
        .WithConstructorArgument( "MainLoopTimeout", MainLoopTimeout );
}
```

Но мне бы не хотелось смешивать конфигурирование и создание зависимостей в одном месте, как то можно это разделить?

Comment: Создать библиотеку, например `public class Config {`, поместить туда параметр `public string MainLoopTimeout { get { return WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings[ "MainLoopTimeout" ];}}` с обращением в Web.Config.

Comment: честно говоря не вижу проблему, вы же в любом случаи конфигурируете передавая параметры. Я бы просто избежал переменной, а просто конфиг в параметр передавал чтоб не портить стройность биндингов)

Comment: @tcpack4 да просто крыша едет на Single responsobility =)

Comment: @tcpack4  а если что то пойдет не так с взятием данных из конфига ?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov может отсутствовать параметр в конфиге, тогда можно в конструкторе класса проверку на null поставить и выкидывать ArgumentNullException или что-либо еще на валидность параметра.

Comment: Нормальное решение у вас, я с NInject точно также работал. Работает уже пару лет, и не мешает

Comment: @Anton Shakalo ох.. у меня и не такая вермишель работает... и темнеменее хочется приучить себя делать все по методологии)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы размышляете верно, вам нужно отделить регистрацию типов в контейнере от конструирования объекта. В вашем случае, я бы воспользовался конструкцией [`ToMethod`](https://lukewickstead.wordpress.com/2013/02/09/howto-ninject-part-2-advanced-features/) и передал бы ему фабричный метод, который бы уже создавал объект.

```
Bind<IRepository>().ToMethod(BuildBookRepository)
```

Конечно-же сам метод `BuildBookRepository` тоже не должен читать конфигурационный файл (*как и сам класс регистрации типов*), а должен делегировать эту задачу другому классу c обязанностью читать конфиг, используя [композицию/агрегацию](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2012/12/vs-vs.html)

```
private IRepository BuildBookRepository(IContext context)   
{           
    string MainLoopTimeout = _config.MainLoopTimeout;

    // Create repository object
}
```

Где `_config` это экземпляр "читальщика" из конфигурационного файла.

Comment: Ваш способ и ваше объяснения стоят друг друга они прекрасны. Скажите есть еще что-то что я должен знать или над чем то подумать?

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov Спасибо. Думаю, разберетесь по ходу дела что вам нужно.